# npm install windows vs raspberry pi, very different with respect to github private module/repo

Tags: git, npm-install

I am trying to use private github repo's as a npm module. 
Rapsberry pi / Debian  vs Windows 10 is behaving very differently even thought they have the same version of npm.

npm - v on windows and rasberry give 5.6.0

I create a directory called "junk" on both and called "npm init". This gives me 
a package.json on both.

npm install git+[https://github.com/**my_user_id**/**project_name**.git](https://github.com/__my_user_id__/__project_name__.git)

On windows it creates node_modules with the a directory for **project_name** containing all the files.

On raspberry, I get the error
/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t [https://github.com/**my_user_id**/**project_name**](https://github.com/__my_user_id__/__project_name__)
remote: Invalid username or password.

Why does this work on windows but not raspberry?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a user account with access to the private repo setup on Windows, but on raspberry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about npm but looks like it prevents git from asking the password interactively. And at windows you have it stored in  system credential manager. You could set up similar at raspberry:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
git ls-remote URL #it should ask for password
npm install....
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent days looking for a solution.